# Python looping doesn't give expected output

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to find the missing elements between arr1 and arr2 but not sure what's the issue with the code, why it's not working. Please suggest.

```
def miss2(arr1, arr2):
    arr3=arr1
    for i in arr1:
        # print(i)
        for j in arr2:
            # print(i,j)
            if i == j:
                arr3.remove(j)

    print(arr3)

arr1=[1,2,3,4]
arr2=[1,2]

miss2(arr1,arr2)
```

result:`[2, 3, 4]` instead of `[3, 4]`

Comment: You need to create a copy not just a new reference `arr3 = arr1[:]`, fixes the problem.

Comment: so silly thank you

Answer (score 3):

Objects in Python are stored by **reference**,which means you didn't assign the value of `arr1` to `arr3`, but a pointer to the object.You can use `is` operator to test if two objects have the same address in memory.

Sequences can be copied by slicing so you can use this to copy a list:

```
arr3 = arr1[:]
```

Also you can use

```
arr3 = list(arr1)
```

Or you can use copy() module:

```
from copy import copy
arr3 = copy(arr1)
```

By the way,you can try this:

```
print [i for i in arr1 if i not in arr2]
```

Answer (score 0):

McGrady is right.
Here is an article tells you more stuff about the reference problem.
[Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference?](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)

And you can use "set"(consider the math concept) data structure instead of "list", here:

```
x = set([1,2,3,4])
y = set([1,2])
x - y
```